# ASP.NET MVC 4 Joining two tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

please may you take a look at my code and point me in the right direction.
I have 2 tables : Product and vProductAndDescription. I need the Name and LisPrice from Product and the Description from vProductAndDescription joined by their ProductID respectively. Am I on the right track at achieving this in my view? Because so far it is just crashing.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string query = "SELECT v.Name, p.ListPrice, LEFT(v.Description, 20) from SalesLT.vProductAndDescription v, SalesLT.Product p WHERE v.ProductID = p.ProductID";
            var list = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query);              
            var result = from a in list.ToList()
                    join b in db.vProductAndDescriptions on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
                    select new
                    {
                        c = a.Name,
                        d = a.ListPrice,
                        e = b.Description
                    };
            return View(result.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name
        </th>
        <th>Price (R)
        </th>
        <th>Description
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in ViewData.Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled by user code, The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'AdventureWorksLT2008R2Model.Product'. A member of the type, 'ProductID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense at all to me because it clearly does have a corresponding column, it's obvious. Surely there is an easier way of joining two tables and displaying them in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call `var list = db.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(query);` trying to create a List of type `Product` but your actual query doesn't return a `ProductID` parameter necessary to create the `Product` type.  Also, what type are you expecting from the line

```
var result = from a in list.ToList()
                join b in db.vProductAndDescriptions on a.ProductID equals b.ProductID
                select new
                {
                    c = a.Name,
                    d = a.ListPrice,
                    e = b.Description
                };
```

To start with, you need a ViewModel to hold your values in, because you aren't passing a whole existing object to your view.

```
public class ProductDescriptionsViewModel {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ListPrice {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

in your View code at the top:

```
@model IEnumerable<YourFullNamespace.ProductDescriptionsViewModel>
```

in your query you are actually making 2 calls on the database, let's see if we can re-arrange things to get one call:

```
string query = "SELECT v.Name as Name, p.ListPrice as ListPrice, LEFT(v.Description, 20) as Description from SalesLT.vProductAndDescription v, SalesLT.Product p WHERE v.ProductID = p.ProductID";
var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProductDescriptionsViewModel>(query);
```

Comment: I was trying to do it with a raw sql query as I just need the Name, ListPrice and first 20 words of the description.

Comment: I'm trying to work out a way to illustrate what changes need to be made to your code here, and I'm sure we can work out how to use a raw sql call.

Comment: I already have the above suggested viewmodel, and it needs to include the ProductID otherwise the a.ProductID part of the var result will not work. I'm getting a few strange errors. Error : The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.String,System.Decimal,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AW_Internet.Models.ProdList]'.

Comment: edited, note the modification to the query, using as for each variable will help EntityFramework match the output of the query to the correct Property on the ViewModel

Comment: I wish i could post my newly edited code. This is really frustrating me. I have the code exactly as it mentioned by you and it is still crashing, with the error mentioned in my last comment. I have tried changing the ViewModel class to IEnumerable types of the two tables respectively but then it refuses to compile and says there is an error at the 'join' - Error : The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'

Comment: I'm responding now from my phone... Maybe try making the SQL call without a class i.e. SqlQuery(query) then iterating through the returned collection and add each to a vm collection.

Comment: Also, a linq expression wouldn't affect performance since the expression is evaluated into a call dynamically (you wouldn't return additional data)

Comment: That could be one way to do it yes, Let me try that. Could you maybe provide some guidelines of iterating through and adding each to a viewmodel collection. I really appreciate your help thus far.

Comment: What I did was simply this: string query = "SELECT p.Name as Name, p.ListPrice as ListPrice, LEFT(v.Description, 20) as Description from SalesLT.vProductAndDescription v, SalesLT.Product p WHERE v.ProductID = p.ProductID";
            var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(query);
            return View(viewModel);

Comment: Question, would there be a way to have a Details page associated with this custom viewmodel? It's difficult cause it needs the ProductID passed but when I embed an actionlink for details all the productID's are zero it seems. How would I go about coding that? Another custom query where i specify the ProductID as the selected record?

Comment: I think if you need the productID, you should just be able to add it as a parameter in the viewmodel and include it in your query

Comment: How would I use that with the .Find(id); function to return the relevant records details? As is normal with the ActionResult Details function.